# Images are not displayed in my home page from model.py

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I have created a form for user to post their stuff, all other stuff works fine only image can't be displayed in my home page

I have tried to overlook again and again the code seems to ok, my guess is the structure of folders of image. Am not really sure how to structure the folders for images. Please help!!

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def PostNew(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.save()
            return redirect('loststuffapp:IndexView')
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'loststuffapp/form.html', {'form': form})
```

**models.py**

```
class Documents(models.Model):
    docs_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,verbose_name="Names in Documents")
    item_type = models.CharField(default="", max_length=100,verbose_name="Item type" )
    police_station = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Police station")
    phone_no = models.CharField(verbose_name="Phone number", max_length=10, blank=False, 
validators=[int_list_validator(sep=''),MinLengthValidator(10),], 
default='0766000000')
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now,verbose_name="Date")
    Description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True,verbose_name="Description")
    pay_no = models.IntegerField(default=0,verbose_name="payment number")
    publish = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    image = models.ImageField(default="add Item image",
                          upload_to="media",blank=False, verbose_name="Images")
"""docstring for Documents"""

    def __str__(self):
        return self.docs_name
```

**forms.py**

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Documents
        fields = ['docs_name', 'item_type', 'police_station','phone_no', 'Description', 'image']
        labels = {'docs_name': 'Name in Documents','item_type':'Item type','police_station':'Police station',
     'phone_no':'Phone number','Description':'Description','image':'Images'
    }
```

**setting.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL ='/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'loststuff/media')
```

**home.html**

```
{% for Doc in documents %}
 <div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-image">

        <p><label style="font-size:15px; font-weight: bold;color: black;">Names in documents:  </label>{{Doc.docs_name}}</p>
        <p><label style="font-size:15px; font-weight: bold;color: black;">Item Type:  </label>{{Doc.item_type}}</p>
        <p><label style="font-size:15px; font-weight: bold;color: black;">Police station:  </label>{{Doc.police_station}}</p>
        <p><label style="font-size:15px; font-weight: bold;color: black;">Phone number:  </label>{{Doc.phone_no}}</p>
        <p><label style="font-size:15px; font-weight: bold;color: black;">Description:  </label>{{Doc.Description}}</p>
        <p><label style="font-size:15px; font-weight: bold;color: black;">Images:  </label><img src = "/media/{{Doc.image.url}}" style="width: 450px; height: 300px;"/></p>
        <p>{{Doc.date}}</p>

</div>
```

```
{% endfor %}
```

urls.py

urlpatterns = [

```
         path('', views.IndexView, name="IndexView"),
         path('IndexView', views.IndexView, name="IndexView"),
         path('PostNew/', views.PostNew, name="PostNew"),
         path('register/', views.register, name="register"),
         path('logout/', views.logout_request, name="logout"),
         path('login/', views.login_request, name="login"),
         path('ContactForm/', views.ContactForm, name="ContactForm"),
         path('About/', views.About, name="About"),
         path('Help/', views.Help, name="Help"),

] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**file structure**

[image]

[image: traceback]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you see the images in `/media`? Based on the code you've shown, it doesn't look like your [binding the upload files to the form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files).

You'll want your view to look something like:

```
@login_required
def PostNew(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.save()
            return redirect('loststuffapp:IndexView')
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'loststuffapp/form.html', {'form': form})
```

Notice the addition of `request.FILES` as the second argument to the form constructor. You'll also want to ensure your upload form sets the `enctype` like so:

```
<form action="{% url 'your-url-here' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

There also looks to be an issue with how you've defined the `image` field in `Documents`. You'll want to update that to look like so:

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="documents", blank=False, verbose_name="Images")
```

Notice I replaced the "media" in the `upload_to` argument. It's already set in `settings.MEDIA_ROOT`. I also removed the `default` argument as it doesn't make sense in this context.

Comment: I see only two picture, but i have been posting many times which means, i was supposed to see many pictures. So I guess at some point it was Ok but I did not notice

Comment: Am little bit confused on how to bind form to an image field, because the example in the link is quite different from mine and still am a beginner in python

Comment: No worries, filled out my answer a bit more to elaborate on how to go about this.

Comment: I have made the changes now I get another error called "Reverse for 'PostNew' not found. 'PostNew' is not a valid view function or pattern name.", Am wondering because this PostNew is the right functon in the view

Comment: Can you post the urls.py?

Comment: Whoops, missed it in your post. When do you get that error? Can you post the traceback?

Comment: In terminal it says "Not Found: /media/add Item image", see the traceback above

Comment: The error your seeing is in the GET request, not the during the form save (POST). Although I think there's a couple issues with how you're defining the `Documents.image` field. I'll update the answer to show the change.